# Does there exist any isomorphism $\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{24})\cong\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_8)\times\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist any isomorphism
$\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{24})\cong\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_8)\times\mathrm{Gl}(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$? If yes, how does the map look?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the chinese remainder theorem, there is a ring isomorphism $u:\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. It induces a group morphism $\varphi:\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})\times\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ because a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ is still a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. It is then clear that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, $\varphi^{-1}$ is defined in the same way using $u^{-1}$ instead of $u$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what would be $\varphi^{-1}$ here?

Comment: If $A\in\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})$ and $B\in\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ then $\varphi^{-1}(A,B)_{i,j}=u^{-1}(a_{i,j},b_{i,j})$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.